# MySQL Installer не устанавливает MySQL Server (did not find packages in the current bundle error)

Tags: mysql, sql, база-данных

Скачал с сайта MySQL инсталлер последней версии, а он предлагает к установке только коннекторы и документацию (режим установки *Custom*). В режиме установки *Server only* инсталлер выдает ошибку:

> mysql installer did not find packages in the current bundle suitable for installation

Как мне установить Workbench и MySQL Server?

Answer (score 1):

Столкнулся с тем же. Я установил более раннюю версию.

Comment: и установил клиент HeidiSQL

Answer (score 0):

зайдите в установка удаление программ и удалите MySQL Installer - Community, после этого начните установку заново. У меня инсталлятор 400 Мб. Все заработало